# XDocument not returning expected elements

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I've done my research and tried many trials, but this has me stumped. I'm probably being thick, but given the follwing XML document, how can I most easly find the UnitTestResult elements?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<TestReport> 
   <TestRun id="5cbd568d-02e4-4003-96c7-3d82cc0c2060" name="neil@HP6550BTS2 2014-09-08 15:23:16" runUser="AS\neil" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2006">   
      <Results>
         <UnitTestResult executionId="c3194ea8-adec-4e50-a4b6-45e244c50963" testId="8e220518-d603-0136-5937-819380dd4738" testName="NewRowMatrixResourceBookingTest" computerName="HP6550BTS2" duration="00:00:00.0204886" startTime="2014-09-08T15:23:32.3595341+01:00" endTime="2014-09-08T15:23:33.8396821+01:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Passed" testListId="2fc4d891-506d-45de-8c61-cf6aa44e8eb2">
            <Output>
            </Output>
         </UnitTestResult>
         <UnitTestResult executionId="c20b289e-4af5-4827-a35d-39360dec984a" testId="d48055d1-0a28-af07-4490-2bfca70dbbcf" testName="MatrixScreen_Checkout_NewScreenVersionLockedReason1" computerName="HP6550BTS2" duration="00:00:07.1635460" startTime="2014-09-08T15:23:33.8466828+01:00" endTime="2014-09-08T15:23:41.0143995+01:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Passed" testListId="2fc4d891-506d-45de-8c61-cf6aa44e8eb2">
            <Output>
            </Output>
         </UnitTestResult>   
      </Results> 
   </TestRun> 
</TestReport>
```

I've tried

`xdoc.Descendants("UnitTestResult")`

and

`xdoc.Elements("TestReport").Elements("TestRun").Elements("Results").Elements("UnitTestResult")`

and also

```
var ns = "http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2006";
var x = from result in testReport.Elements("TestReport").Elements(XName.Get(ns, "TestRun")).Elements("Results").Elements("UnitTestResult")
```

and various other variations, but they all yield an empty enumeration.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just

```
XNamespace ns = "http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2006";

yourXmlDocument.Descendants(ns + "UnitTestResult");
```

Notice the explicit definition of `XNamespace`, otherwise the compiler will infer the type as `string` not `XNamespace`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless explicitly declared otherwise, descendants of the node where default namespace declared inherits the same namespace. So you need to use the same namespace prefix for `<Results>` and `<UnitTestResult>` :

```
XNamespace ns = "http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2006";
var x = from result in xdoc.Elements("TestReport")
                           .Elements(ns+"TestRun")
                           .Elements(ns+"Results")
                           .Elements(ns+"UnitTestResult");
```

Answer (score 1):

All other answers include namespace declarations, which might be right solutions. You might want to ignore namespaces with namespace-agnostic solution:

```
xdoc.Descendants()
    .Where(node => node.Name.LocalName == "UnitTestResult")
```

which would yield results regardless of defined namespaces

Comment: this worked for me, but I had to add Root, like this:  xdoc.Root.Descendants()
    .Where(node => node.Name.LocalName == "UnitTestResult")

Answer (score 0):

Although using the `XmlDocument` class rather than the `XDocument` class, I had similar problems a while ago when trying to manipulate a `.testsettings` file to ensure that Code Coverage was enabled.  The code I used to get this working is below, which you could try using as a basis to get yourself up and running.  I think the key part is using the `ms` namespace suffix as well as declaring the namespace.

```
XmlDocument testSettings = new XmlDocument();
testSettings.Load(fullSettingsPath);

// Load the XML Namespace manager we need for reading the .testsettings file
XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(testSettings.NameTable);
xmlnsm.AddNamespace("ms", "http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010");

XmlNodeList coverageNodes = testSettings.SelectNodes(
    @"ms:TestSettings/ms:Execution/ms:AgentRule/ms:DataCollectors/ms:DataCollector[@uri='datacollector://microsoft/CodeCoverage/1.0']/ms:Configuration/CodeCoverage",
    xmlnsm);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void AtribesAndInnerTexts(string pathToFile)
{

  var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
  doc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(pathToFile));
    // desired node in this case UnitTestResult
  var UnitTestResults = doc.GetElementsByTagName("UnitTestResult");
    foreach (var unitTestResult in UnitTestResults)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((XmlElement) unitTestResult).GetAttribute("executionId"));
        Console.WriteLine(((XmlElement) unitTestResult).InnerText);
    }
}
```